# How to install Debian 7 and PP5 in 2020?

Tags: php, debian

I have an old installation of TYPO3 (6.4) and I want to move it to another supplier. I can export everything but I cannot install a working server that can run the applications from the old website.

I am sure it has something to do with PHP and my solution I think would be to install PHP 5.4.4 on either Debian 7 or a newer Debian distribtion.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you :)

Comment: PHP5.4 is super outdated and insecure. Switch to the latest PHP version for security and in all honesty, better code. PHP4 + PHP5.4 definitely contributed to PHPs bad rep

Comment: Did you try something like `apt-get install php5`

Comment: There's plenty links on how to do this [like this](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04-debian-9-8.html) but I agree with treyBake that it's an absolutely terrible idea. Update the PHP version, unless they're huge apps it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I did try apt-get install php5 without any luck. I also know that php5 is waaaay outdated. Never the less this is the only php that this site works on and the only way I can move it from present hosting company to a cheaper temporary host.

Comment: The one alan link to is version 5.6 - i need an even older 5.4 :(

Answer (score 0):

There never was a TYPO3 version 6.4. maybe 6.0.4 or 6.2.4 ?

you can try to install a virtual maschine with an old linux image with that old PHP version.
But that should be only local and only for viewing the old site.

In general you don't need a working server as all neccessary data is in the database (and filesystem).

Install a TYPO3 verion 7 (also outdated, but runs on PHP 7.2) as an intermediate step and insert a copy of the old database and the filesystem (fileadmin/*). Then run upgrade wizard (do an upgrade for all extensions as possible)

Repeat for TYPO3 versions 8, 9 until your database is converted to latest version and matching extensions.

Meanwhile you probably need to change the rendering as the old installation was probably based on CSC (css_styled_content) while there is FSC (fluid_styled_content) which resuls in other HTML markup and other CSS.

---

Or was it even a 4.6?

Then you need a prior step with TYPO3 6.2 to convert all file references to FAL. therefore you need an old PHP 5.6 to execute the upgrade wizards. (stay with a local virtual machine)